# guava - filter and transform map

Tags: dictionary, filtering, guava, transformation

What is the most efficient way to filter and transform the values of a `Map`. I am used to using `FluentIterable` for these kind of operations, but it doesn't apply to a `Map`.

Is `Maps.transformValues(Maps.filterValues(map, predicate), function)` the best choice?

Comment: A quick look at the [javadocs](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/index.html) shows that `transformValues` and `filterValues` return decorators.  So, the complexity for `get`, `put`, etc... depends on the complexity of the `filter` and `transform` functions.  A full copy *might* be more efficient.

Comment: Do you mean that I should make a new map at the end, or also after the `filterValues`?

Comment: It would depend on how you use the `Map<K, V>`.  The main memory overhead for the decorator `Map<K, V>`s are the decorator functions.  You generally encounter the complexity of both of the functions whenever you access the decorator `Map<K, V>`(s) though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic solution is that if you KNOW that the only way you will use the `Map` is to iterate the entries exactly ONCE, then what you have it fine. However, if you plan to use `get`, `put` or if you might iterate it more than once, creating a new `Map` is advisable so that the work of filter and transform is only done once.

```
Maps.newHashMap(Maps.transformValues(Maps.filterValues(map, predicate), function));
```

The ordering of `filter` and `transform` is correct here so that you don't `transform` values that would have been filtered.